# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'func' Only With C++ Invocation

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

I've been working on integrating a scripting subsystem into an existing architecture and have been employing the use of the boost.python library.

My goal is to have the python environment that I create to be identical, or as close to, that which is expected in existing code - i.e. preserving namespace conventions, etc. The trick here is that I have two source files illustrating a use case that works if I fire up the interpreter standalone but do not work in my environment, meaning I must be doing something wrong.

As a disclaimer I'm not an experienced python user so I'm bound to butcher the correct terminology here.

### **core.py**

```
import sys

def func():    
    print "sys is",sys

print "call from core"  
func()
```

### **main.py**

```
import core

print "---------GLOBALS-------------"
globals_ = dict(globals())
for g in globals_:
    print g

print "--------------LOCALS---------"   
locals_ = dict(locals())
for l in locals_:
    print l

print "call from main"
core.func()
```

*Invoking `python main.py` from command prompt*

```
call from core
sys is <module 'sys' (built-in)>
---------GLOBALS-------------
core
__builtins__
__name__
__file__
__doc__
__package__
--------------LOCALS---------
core
g
__builtins__
__file__
globals_
__package__
__name__
__doc__
call from main
sys is <module 'sys' (built-in)>
```

I understand the steps as being:

1. main invokes **import** to import core.py.
2. The core module is loaded; the core namespace and the attributes it provides become accessible from main. In the process, core invokes its func method, printing what is bound to `sys`.
3. main invokes the function bound under the module core.

*Example of how I bring up the scripting environment:*

```
void Run()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    if(PyErr_Occurred())
    {
        PyErr_Print();
    }

    // Install builtins in __main__
    boost::python::object main_module = boost::python::import(ToplevelScope.c_str());
    boost::python::object main_namespace = main_module.attr("__dict__");
    boost::python::dict main_dictionary = boost::python::extract<boost::python::dict>(main_namespace);
    main_dictionary["__builtins__"] =  boost::python::handle<>(boost::python::borrowed(PyEval_GetBuiltins()));

    // Load modules
    LoadModule("core.py",GetDataForCore());
    LoadModule("main.py",GetDataForMain());
}

void LoadModule(std::string name, char* data)
{
    // First, see if the module already exists.
    PyObject* new_module;
    if( new_module = PyImport_AddModule(name.c_str()) )
    {
        if( PyDict_GetItemString(new_module,"__name__") )
        {
            return; // already loaded. no work to do.
        }
    }

    // Initialize default namespace parameters - global, local
    boost::python::dict base_dict = boost::python::dict();
    base_dict["__builtins__"] = boost::python::handle<>(PyImport_AddModule("__builtin__"));
    base_dict["__name__"] = name.c_str();
    base_dict["__file__"] = name.c_str();
    base_dict["__doc__"] = "None";
    base_dict["__package__"] = name.c_str();

    boost::python::exec(    data,
                            boost::python::dict(base_dict),  // make a copy of base_dict for both global & local
                            boost::python::dict(base_dict) );
}
```

*Resultant output:*

```
call from core
sys is <module 'sys' (built-in)>
---------GLOBALS-------------
core
__builtins__
__name__
__file__
__doc__
__package__
--------------LOCALS---------
core
g
__builtins__
__file__
globals_
__package__
__name__
__doc__
call from main
[LOG] Framework error while loading script main.py.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'func'
```

It appears that the function in core somehow isn't accessible to main even after an import.

I suspect this has to do with me not fully initializing the core module. Replacing exec with PyRun_String, PyImport_ImportModule... and they all yield the same result. Here I'm creating a copy of a base dictionary with **name** set to the module name (core in this case) and supplying it as the global & local dictionaries.

I think that I'm not fully initializing the module somehow and will be doing a lot more reading to put it together... Any insight will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Why have you created your own load module function, rather than using `PyImport_AddModule` as you do for `__builtins__`? Also, the `LoadModule` function doesn't actually seem to be loading the module, rather just executing the module code and then disposing of the module.

Comment: @Dunes Thanks! I have a `LoadModule` function because the process for getting at the text buffer is quite involved. I have my scripts in RAM bundled in my own class and query said class to get the buffer among other things.

Sorry; I omitted a step where I do call `PyImport_AddModule`. Updating post. [The doc](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/import.html) implies this won't do the load though (`This function does not load or import the module; if the module wasn’t already loaded, you will get an empty module object`). I don't know how to "load" the module instance apart from to exec its code.

Comment: After further review I think I have to Import on the newly created module object to populate its structures. As documented [here](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/import.html), it looks like `PyImport_ExecCodeModule` after compiling my string is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems likes you're trying to reinvent the wheel. `boost::python::import` does exactly what you want to do. Loads a module, or retrieves it from `sys.modules` if it's already been imported before. If you don't want to use boost then you can use `PyObject* PyImport_ImportModule(const char *name)`. Just make sure the module is on python's path.

However, if the module doesn't exist as a file (say the source only exists in memory), then the following will recreate that functionality (it doesn't do any error checking, you'll need to add that yourself).

```
py::object LoadModule(std::string name, const char* module_source)
{
    namespace py = boost::python;

    // create module name and filenames
    py::object name_str(py::str(name.c_str()));
    std::string file = name;
    file += ".py";
    py::object file_str(py::str(file.c_str()));

    // get helper modules
    py::object types(py::import("types"));
    py::object sys(py::import("sys"));

    if (py::dict(sys.attr("modules")).has_key(name_str)) {
        return sys.attr("modules")[name_str];
    }

    // create empty module
    py::object module(types.attr("ModuleType")(name_str));

    // init module dict
    py::dict base_dict = py::extract<py::dict>(module.attr("__dict__"));
    base_dict["__builtins__"] = py::import("__builtins__");
    base_dict["__name__"] = name_str;
    base_dict["__file__"] = file_str;

    // execute module code in module context
    py::exec(module_source, base_dict, base_dict);

    // add module to sys.modules
    sys.attr("modules")[name] = module;

    return module;
}
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! This is a lot cleaner than what I've managed to get working which uses base Py_ calls.